# Finding argmax of a sum of logarithms

Tags: calculus, logarithms, maxima-minima, maximum-likelihood

$\ln\mathscr{L} = \ln(1 - \Phi(x)) + \ln(\Phi(x))$

Is there any general method to maximize $\ln\mathscr{L}$ for argument $\Phi(x)$?
In other words, to do $\arg\limits_\Phi \max (\ln(1 - \Phi(x)) + \ln(\Phi(x))) ?$

p.s. solved by Clement C. in his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597458/finding-argmax-of-a-sum-of-logarithms#comment7395394_3597458).

Comment: Since $$\ln(1-\Phi(x)) + \ln \Phi(x) = \ln\left((1-\Phi(x))\Phi(x)\right)$$
and $\ln$ is increasing, you have
$$
\arg\!\max (\ln(1-\Phi(x)) + \ln \Phi(x) ) = \arg\!\max\, (1-\Phi(x))\Phi(x)
$$ which may be much more convenient

Comment: Excuse me, how exactly did you get the first one? I know only sum of logarithms is a logarithm of multiplication (lnb + lnc = ln(b*c)).

Comment: That's exactly what I used, for $b=1-\Phi(x)$ and $c=\Phi(x)$.

Comment: Did not notice the bracket first =)
That helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!