# Estimating indicator of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Given selection of i.i.d's ${X_1 \dots X_n} \sim \mathscr{N}(\theta, 1)$ ($\theta$ is unknown), how to express probability of $X_i > 0$?
(and express it without normal distrbution' cdf which contains error function and thus unhandy?)

Some thoughts:
Let some derived random value D be Bernoulli-distributed with parameter = $I(x > 0)$. Probability of $x > 0$ can be expressed through original normal distribution' cdf like this: $p(x > 0) = 1 - cdf(0)$.

So likelihood logarithm of the said Bernoulli parameter will be:

$lnLikelihood = ln(p(x > 0)) + ln(p(x <= 0)) = ln(1 - cdf(0)) + ln(cdf(0))$

To maximize the rightmost part, according to the [Clement C. comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597458/finding-argmax-of-a-sum-of-logarithms#comment7395394_3597458), replace $ln(1 - cdf(0)) + ln(cdf(0))$ by $(1 - cdf(0))cdf(0) = cdf(0) - cdf^2(0)$. After cdf(0) substitution (note that cdf(0) means cdf of $\mathscr{N}(\theta, 1))$ we get a trivial square equation ($-x^2 + x + 0 = 0$, which roots are $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt(5)}{-2}$, and given a = -1 < 0, we conclude that maximum is in $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now there is a contradiction. How can not maximum depend on the unknown $\theta$? Somewhere here I need to express $\theta$ of the original normal distribution.

Comment: If $\theta$ is known, why do you need to estimate the probability?

Comment: Updated. (estimate > express)

Comment: It is expressed using the cdf $\Phi$, whose value at a given $\theta$ can be exactly found using software or its approximate value can be found from printed tables. However, since you have added the `maximum-likelihood` tag one would imagine $\theta$ to be unknown.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to "arg-maximize" $\Phi$ later in the likelihood logarithm. I tried to, and obtained $\Phi = \frac{1}{2}$ without $\theta$, which seems to be wrong ($\Phi$ must depend on $\theta$).

Comment: Just edited the question to clarify right conditions. How to re-open it now?

Comment: Do you want to find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$? If you share your work/thoughts on the problem, then people will vote to reopen your post.

Comment: I want to find the MLE of P(Y = 1) expressed through the unknown $\theta$.
I tried at least two dedicated ways:
1) Roughly express likelihood logarithm through probability of X > 0 (something like $ln\mathscr{L}_(Y=1) = ln(p(Y=1)) + ln(p(Y=0)) = ln(1 - cdf_\mathscr{N}(x)) + ln(cdf_\mathscr{N}(x))$ - that causes use of CDF of normal distribution, so the error function appears. That is the wrong way.

Comment: 2) Let $\mathscr{\Phi}$ = cdf(x) and follow the 1). After some trivial calculations, likelihood logarithm is $ln(\Phi(x) - \Phi^2(x))$, the roots of $\Phi(x) - \Phi^2(x)$ are $(-1 \pm \sqrt{5}) / (-2)$, and the desired maximum is 1/2, which is nonsense, because is must be expressed through unknown $\theta$, for obvious reasons (probability of x > 0 depends on expected of normal distribution).

Comment: Please add these info in your post by editing it, not in comments.

Comment: Did it an hour ago. How can it be re-opened now?

Comment: I have voted to reopen, but still not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Haha seems totally my fault! =)
I mean, the said Bernoulli parameter seems to depend from $\theta$, and I need to somehow link them in my estimatons, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $Y_{1},\dotsc, Y_n$, where $Y_i=I(X_i>0)$ indicators for the event that $Y_i$ is positive. Then $Y_{i}$ are i.i.d Bernoulli random variables with $p=P(X_1>0)$. Let $N=\sum Y_i$ which is a binomially distributed random variable with $n$ trials and probability of success $p$. Using maximum likelihood one can show that the MLE estimator of $p$
$$
\hat{p}=N/n
$$

Comment: Notice there is a non-zero first parameter in $\mathscr{N}$. Is that estimation still correct? I mean, I need an estimation expressed through original normal distribution using $\theta$.